# What should be the output here?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

In my opinion, the output should be `EMAM` 5 times, but it prints `EMAM` 6 times. Can anyone sort this out? A little explanation will be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while(n < printf("EMAM\n"))
    {
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes @StoryTeller

Comment: Windows uses CRLF so `\n` will be printed out as `\r\n`

Comment: Did you intentionally revert my edits? Please check the edit history and keep the changes which do not conflict with your intent.

Comment: @Student I rolled back your edit, the formatting of which suggested the output of literal "5" or "6" which is not at all what OP is asking about.

Comment: @EmamHossen, can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 7):

It prints 5 times due to n values 0, 1, 2 , 3, 4, and 5. When n is 5, it doesn't loop again but it still printed out the message.

Comment: Of course. The condition needs to checked one additional time, and that means another call to `printf`. Have an upvote!